# I use react-create-app and got this error => ./src/index.css (./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader

I'm using `create-react-app` for a project and all was perfectly fine until this morning (the font was never an issue either).
I got this error by running `npm start` =>

```
./src/index.css (./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
Error: Can't resolve './fonts/Plain-Medium.otf'
```

I tried to rebuild `css-loader` and reinstall `webpack` but without success.

Anyone know where this could come from ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is bug in `css-loader`.disable `postcss-normalize-url` in cssnano (`normalizeUrl: false`)

Answer (score 1):

You can be of that image in src/ folder not in public/

It resolves on my end and I hope its help full to you
Thanks.

Comment: it did resolve for me as well. I was trying to configure the background image in my React/tailwind app.