# How to disable postcss normalize-url in cssnano

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader

*There is bug in css-loader.disable postcss-normalize-url in cssnano (normalizeUrl: false)*

Newbie here. How do I go about implementing the fix stated above in a react app created with create-react-app? Any help would be appreciated.

The fix was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64587337/i-use-react-create-app-and-got-this-error-src-index-css-node-modules-rea).